Uniform convergence of entire functions on a compact domain
Let $\Omega$ be a compact set in $\mathbb C$ whose boundary is a polygon and
$f_n$  be an entire function for each $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $(f_n)$ uniformly converges on $\Omega$.
It is well-known that $(f_n')$ converges uniformly on every compact subset of $\Omega^\circ$, where $\Omega^\circ$ is the interior of $\Omega$.
My question is

Does $(f_n')$ necessarily converges uniformly on $\Omega$?

It could be a simple question for an expert in complex analysis.
Could anyone give the answer or let me know some related references?

Let $\Omega$ be a  triangle contained in the closed unit disk with $1$ as  one of the vertices. Let $f_n(z)=z^{n}/n$ and $f=0$.

@geetha290krm, thanks a lot for a quick answer!
